# SQL query runs very slow when using format date function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, query-optimization

Using SQL Server 2016. I have the following table that has a large number of records (30 mil+).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE1]
(
    [DATE_TIME] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [TEXT] [VARCHAR](500) NULL,
    [MSG] [VARCHAR](500) NULL,
    [MSGID] [INT] NULL,
    [SEVERITY] VARCHAR(50) NULL
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [TABLE1_IX1] 
ON [dbo].[TABLE1] ([DATE_TIME] ASC, [MSGID] ASC, [SEVERITY] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,  
                      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
                      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The following query is very slow:

```
SELECT 
    [DATE_TIME], [TEXT], [MSG], [MSGID], [SEVERITY] 
FROM      
    [TABLE1] 
WHERE
    FORMAT([DATE_TIME], 'yyyy-MM-dd') IN ('2019-06-25', '2019-06-24',etc.....) 
    AND [MSGID] IN (8016, 11, 3072, 23, 3062, etc....) 
    AND [SEVERITY] <> 'Medium' 
ORDER BY 
    [DATE_TIME] DESC
```

Please help to optimize.

Comment: Considering [DATE_TIME] is indeed a datetime,  then convert to date   ...  WHERE convert(date,[DATE_TIME]) in (...)

Comment: Yes, it runs much faster using this conversion, thank you John for your quick answer. Please post it so I can mark as "answered"

Comment: As you have discovered. format() has some great functionality, but performance will suffer.  I try to use format() sparingly or on final results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format has some great functionality, but performance can suffer.

Try

```
WHERE convert(date,[DATE_TIME]) in (...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use direct date comparisons.  Because you seem to have a range, I would recommend:

```
WHERE [DATE_TIME] >= ? AND
      [DATE_TIME] < '2019-06-26' AND
      [MSGID] IN (8016, 11, 3072, 23, 3062, etc....) AND
      [SEVERITY] <> 'Medium'
```

This can make optimal use of an index and partitions, if available.  You can also convert to a `date`.  That is the one use of a function that will also use an index.  I don't know if convert will prune partitions.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, will take note of this method! I am however happy with the above solution using CONVERT function that solved my problem